# when Ant design drawer opened body scroll its working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, antd

I have using ant design drawer, when these drawer have opened whole page is scrolled. how to stop  page scroll ?

using ant version are below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BU1g.png)

Comment: Please dont add code as images but add it as actual text into the question.

Comment: ok @FabianSchöner thanks for your information, do you know the answer

Comment: To provide a proper answer you need to provide code so we can look at it, test it and find out whats wrong. By the information you shared right now it could be literally anything.

Comment: more code will certainly help here! at least a snippet of the relevant bits. are you making sure to import the `antd.css` file in the app root? i know this has stumped me a few times before.